# Reading external images

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I've looked around and have tried many fixes, but I can't seem to find one that works.

I'm making a simple frogger game, and I originally had all of my sprites loaded in the project directory like `img/spritename.png`:

```java
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("img/map.png"));
```

or

```java
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(sprite));
```

Everything worked fine and dandy, but I went to move all of my images to an external directory so I can create an installer for it.

`"C:\Program Files\DIR\img\"` and all of the sprites no longer load.

The code I thought would fix it but didn't

```java
    BufferedImage image = null;

    File dir = new File(Config.imgDir + "map.png");
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(dir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (image == null) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Config code:

```java
public static String imgDir = "C:/Program Files/EmulousSoft/Frogger/img/";
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm sure it's simple, but every time I try different methods, I get `"Value cannot be a null"`, `"cannot find directory"` or this.

Comment: I think you should use path in windows like this C:\\Program\\Files\\EmulousSoft

Comment: @hatefAlipoor Windows (and as a result, Java) supports using the forward slash `/` as a path separator, so using `C:/Program Files/EmulousSoft/Frogger/img/` is perfectly valid.

Comment: What exact error are you getting? Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: @DmitriyPopov im getting no errors actually, just the images will not load when i ry externally instead of inside the project directory.

Comment: Confirm that the path string is what you think it might be: `System.out.println(Config.imgDir + "map.png");`. Make sure it actually exists: `File dir = new File(Config.imgDir + "map.png"); if (!dir.exists()) { System.err.println("Can not locate file!"); }`. See if you are allowed to read it from the OS: `File dir = new File(Config.imgDir + "map.png"); if (dir.exists() && !dir.canRead()) { System.err.println("You don't have permission to read file!"); }`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd I have tried what you said and it prints out no errors. 
Im not sure what the issue is with it not actually loading the images.

Comment: Not the problem here it seems, but don't use `new File(Config.imgDir + "map.png")`. Always use `new File(Config.imgDir, "map.png")` (two arguments), as it's guards against silly mistakes as missing slash at end of `imgDir`. :-)